# Flush viewcomponent early

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

is it possible to flush view component result early?

https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/18/flushing-the-document-early/

Currently my page is blocked trying to render 5-6 view components, i would like to flush them early then fill it up.

Is that possible in .net core mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the link you included has to do with anything. Simply, no, it's not possible. View components are rendered in place during the parsing of the Razor view. You can't continue without them or the eventual HTML they return would not end up in the appropriate place in the document or at all.

That said, nothing you do in a view component should take any significant amount of time. If you've got some kind of long-running process going, that needs to be moved some place else. If you're waiting on a return from an API or something, you can potentially employ caching to speed up the rendering. Long and short, the problem is down to what's happening in your view components and why they're taking so long to render in the first place, which we have no visibility into. Short of that, there's nothing else to be done.